# Can Make "assume-new" globally?

Tags: unix, makefile, gnu-make

By default, Make will "touch" the supplied target file to "bring it up to date".
To avoid this, you can use [this option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary):

```
   -W file, --what-if=file, --new-file=file, --assume-new=file
        Pretend that the target file has just been  modified.   When  used
        with  the -n flag, this shows you what would happen if you were to
        modify that file.  Without -n, it is almost the same as running  a
        touch  command  on the given file before running make, except that
        the modification time is changed only in the imagination of  make.
```

Is there an equivalent setting *in the Makefile itself* (perhaps a `MAKEFLAGS` option) to assume this option globally for all targets defined in the Makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works: `MAKEFLAGS=--assume-new=$(MAKECMDGOALS)`

Are there any negative side-effects of doing it this way?

Comment: Note that `MAKECMDGOALS` only contains the goals provided on the command line; you specifically asked for all targets defined in the Makefile.  If you backed up a little bit and described what it is you actually want to accomplish it would be simpler to answer your question.